# alterar class label de acordo com texto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring

Pessoal alguém poderia me ajudar com esse js por favor?

preciso que o label altere de acordo com o texto, se for "vitória" fica success e for "derrota" fica danger, segue código abaixo:

nota o meu ${resultad.statusResultados} traz do banco apenas "Vitória" e "Derrota" e ele imprime essa informação na tela, ou seja, realmente o meu js deve estar ruim :/

- > Script

  ```
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("span").each(function () {
              if ($(this).text() === "Vitória") {
                  //limpa class anterior
                  $(this).removeAttr('class');
                  //adiciona class desejada 
                  $(this).addClass('label label-success');
              } else if ($(this).text() === "Derrota") {
                  //limpa class anterior
                  $(this).removeAttr('class');
                  //adiciona class desejada 
                  $(this).addClass('label label-danger');
              }
          });
      });
  </script>
  ```
- > html

  ```
                                  <table class="table">
                                      <thead>
                                          <tr>
                                          </tr>
                                      </thead>
                                      <tbody>
                                          <c:forEach items="${listaResultados}" var="resultad">
                                              <tr>
                                                  <td>${resultad.jogadorTemp}</td>
                                                  <td>${resultad.placar1}</td>
                                                  <td>${resultad.placar2}</td>
                                                  <td>${resultad.oponenteTemp}</td>
                                                  <td>${resultad.momento}</td>
                                                  <td><span class="label label-success">${resultad.statusResultados}</span></td>
                                              </tr>
                                          </c:forEach>
                                      </tbody>
                                  </table>
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pesquise pelos `$("tbody td")` 
e verifique o valor com  `$(this).html()` ao invez de  `$(this).text()`
Como o codigo abaixo

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var rt = $("tbody td").each(function () {
        if ($(this).html() === "Vitória") {
            //limpa class anterior
            $(this).removeAttr('class');
            //adiciona class desejada 
            $(this).addClass('label label-success');
        } else if ($(this).html() === "Derrota") {
            //limpa class anterior
            $(this).removeAttr('class');
            //adiciona class desejada 
            $(this).addClass('label label-danger');

        }
    });
    console.log(rt);
});
```

[Veja um exemplo funcionando aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/o5vw33w1/)

Comment: Marcos realmente o seu código esta correto, testei seu exemplo no link, mas quando coloco dentro do meu .jsp ele não roda algo deve estar conflitando que impende isso de funcionar.

Comment: aperta f12 e vai em  console, e coloque o que está aparecendo de erro aqui, ai poderei ajudar melhor,  vai no  navegador que estiver usando

Comment: home:34 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at home:34
(anonymous) @ home:34 - 

( e ele aponta para esse linha do script: )

  -  $(document).ready(function () {

Comment: verfique se o arquivo Jquery está sendo chamado, e se ele consta antes do  script pois esse erro diz que o  Jquery não está definido no momento que a função está sendo executada

Comment: Caso isso não resolva tente verificar o  [jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: eu colei o jquery dentro da <head>

Comment: é, não rolou! vou continuar tentando aqui.

Comment: eheh, bom  boa sorte no mais, mas veirifica se  o caminho do Jquery está correto, ou tenta usar javascript puro também seria uma  opição

Comment: Cara, "Para que funcione corretamente, no seu HTML você deve importar primeiro o jQuery e depois o seu script"

que bobagem né hahahahaha

resolvido!!!!

Vlw Marcos, obrigado pela ajuda tb.

Comment: haha, que bom  que resolveu,  kkkk  pois é vc tem  q referenciar antes a biblioteca como  havia dito

Comment: se a respostar tiver te ajudado marca com ✓✓

Comment: Vc falou e eu não me atentei, vc esta correto! queria dar a solução no texto que vc diz isso e não no código la em cima, como faço?

Comment: Basta editar sua resposta e colocar abaixo dela a solução